# "Error loading MySQLdb module" when installing custom app

Tags: python, mysql

I am installing a custom app that needs MySQL, which I already had working so I am a bit confused on what's going on.

Anyways here is the error:

```
Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'final', 1),
  but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0
```

Tried

```
sudo pip uninstall MySQL-python
```

then

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

which worked...

```
Successfully installed MySQL-python
```

still the same error

```
Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'final', 1), 
  but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Please provide more information about your system, eg. which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which python version?

Comment: using Ubuntu 13.04, I am unsure of what mysql is installed... what command do I run to check?

Comment: Try `mysql --version`

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `apt-get` and pip each installed their own version of the library.

Try removing system MySQL with `sudo apt-get remove python-mysqldb`, and
you should have something like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python-mysqldb
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 196 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 109333 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-mysqldb (1.2.3-2ubuntu1) ...
```